# Calculation of Percentage for Rows within particular range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a List of students name and Marks Stored in a table like below.

```
CREATE TABLE StudentsList(StudentId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                              Name  VARCHAR(50),
                              Marks INT);


INSERT INTO StudentsList(Name, Marks)
      VALUES('Student A', 20),
            ('Student B', 45),
            ('Student C', 90),
            ('Student D', 81),
            ('Student E', 50),
            ('Student F', 10),
            ('Student G', 85),
            ('Student H', 41),
            ('Student I', 66),
            ('Student J', 65),
            ('Student K', 05),
            ('Student L', 20),
            ('Student M', 19),
            ('Student N', 80),
            ('Student O', 90),
            ('Student P', 91),
            ('Student Q', 10),
            ('Student R', 29);
```

I want to Group the no of students based on the mark range and percentage they contribute in whole.

```
    MarkRange   NoOfStudents  Percentage
      0 - 20       4             22.22
     20 - 50       5             27.77  
     50 - 70       3             16.66 
     70 - 90       3             16.66  
     90            3             16.66
```

I Tried the Below Query and Brought the Result for Students between 0 -20

```
SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100
  FROM StudentsList,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
          FROM StudentsList) AS T 
         WHERE Marks >= 0 and  Marks < 20
```

How can I do this by using single Query

Comment: @saharsh Shah - Thanks for reply Its working Gr8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.minRange, ' - ', A.maxRange) MarkRange, COUNT(sl.Name) NoOfStudents, 
    (SELECT COUNT(sl.Name) / COUNT(*) * 100 FROM StudentsList) Percentage
FROM studentslist sl 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 id, 0 minRange, 20 maxRange 
    UNION 
    SELECT 2 id, 20 minRange, 50 maxRange 
    UNION 
    SELECT 3 id, 50 minRange, 70 maxRange 
    UNION 
    SELECT 4 id, 70 minRange, 90 maxRange 
    UNION 
    SELECT 5 id, 90 minRange, 100 maxRange 
    ) AS A ON sl.Marks >= A.minRange AND sl.Marks < A.maxRange 
GROUP BY A.id;
```

Comment: You can do this in another way as create a table for percentage range in a table and directly join that table you find query faster and optimized way

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100, '0 - 20' AS Range
      FROM StudentsList,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
              FROM StudentsList) AS T 
             WHERE Marks >= 0 and  Marks < 20
    UNION 
    SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100, '20 - 50' AS Range
      FROM StudentsList,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
              FROM StudentsList) AS T 
             WHERE Marks >= 20 and  Marks < 50
    UNION 
    SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100, '50 - 70' AS Range
      FROM StudentsList,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
              FROM StudentsList) AS T 
             WHERE Marks >= 50 and  Marks < 70
    UNION 
    SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100, '70 - 90' AS Range
      FROM StudentsList,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
              FROM StudentsList) AS T 
             WHERE Marks >= 70 and  Marks < 90
   UNION 
   SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100, '90 Above' AS Range
     FROM StudentsList,
          (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
             FROM StudentsList) AS T 
            WHERE Marks >= 90
```

I found an Answer Using Union.

If there is some other solution kindly suggest me

Comment: +1 It's a good answer but your code doesn't compile in sqlfiddler, but if you want to fix it - simply change every occurrence of `as Range` with `as 'Range'` - see [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cf9a/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'number of students', COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100 as 'Percentage', '0 - 20' AS 'Range' 
  FROM StudentsList,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
          FROM StudentsList) AS T 
         WHERE Marks >= 0 and  Marks < 20
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100  as 'Percentage', '20 - 50' AS 'Range'
  FROM StudentsList,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
          FROM StudentsList) AS T 
         WHERE Marks >= 0 and  Marks >= 20 and Marks < 50
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100 as 'Percentage', '50 - 70' AS 'Range'
  FROM StudentsList,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
          FROM StudentsList) AS T 
         WHERE Marks >= 0 and  Marks >= 70 and Marks < 90
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100 as 'Percentage', '70 - 90' AS 'Range'
  FROM StudentsList,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
          FROM StudentsList) AS T 
         WHERE Marks >= 0 and  Marks >= 70 and Marks < 90
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) , COUNT(*)/(T.total)* 100 as 'Percentage', 'Above 90' AS 'Range'
  FROM StudentsList,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
          FROM StudentsList) AS T 
         WHERE Marks >= 0 and  Marks >= 90 
order by 3
```

output:

```
NUMBER OF STUDENTS  PERCENTAGE      RANGE
4                   22.2222         0 - 20
5                   27.7778         20 - 50
3                   16.6667         50 - 70
3                   16.6667         70 - 90
3                   16.6667         Above 90
```

You can see how it runs ***[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cf9a/17)***

Comment: See there are three 16.66 Students Group So as per ur query its going to show single.I have posted same thing above.Kindly check it out.